# How can I get file's 'lastModified' in Google Drive API v3?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I recently decided to migrate from Drive API v2 to v3.

In v2, `files().get(fileId)` returns almost all attributes, but in v3, it doesn't return the `lastModified`, which is very essential for me. Is there anyway I can do it in v3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drive API v3 full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the `fields` query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. See [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).